# Segfault на ровном месте

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Доброго времени суток. Пишу достаточно простую программку под Linux. Вот кусок кода в котором вылазит ошибка сегментации:

```
void GetNames(vector<string> &names, vector<string> &types) { // Cчитывание и запись нужных sm-переменных из текст. файла в матрицу

if (!FlashHere()) return;

string buf;
unsigned int num = 0;
ifstream in(NAMES_DIR);
while (!in.eof()) {
    getline(in, buf, ';');
    num++;
            cout << num << endl;
}

    num = num -1;

names.resize(num);
types.resize(num);
    in.clear();
in.seekg(0, ios::beg); //возврат потока в начало файла

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {

            getline(in, buf, '.');
            types[i] = buf;

    getline(in, buf, ';');
    names[i] = buf;

            cout<< "|" << names[i] << "|" << types[i] << "|" << endl;
}
in.close();
```

}

```
void InitFBD(vector<string> &names, vector<string> &types, Shm &mymem) {



    for (unsigned int num = 0; num < names.size(); num++) {

        if (types[num] == "bool" && mymem.getType(names[num].c_str()) == BOOL)
                    {cout<< num << names[num] << " is ok"<< endl;continue;}
        else if (types[num] == "float" && mymem.getType(names[num].c_str()) == FLOAT)
             {cout<< num << names[num] << " is ok"<< endl;continue;}
        else if (types[num] == "short" && mymem.getType(names[num].c_str()) == SHORT)
             {cout<< num << names[num] << " is ok"<< endl;continue;}
        else if (types[num] == "long" && mymem.getType(names[num].c_str()) == LONG)
             {cout<< num << names[num] << " is ok"<< endl;continue;}
                    else{ cout<< num << " "<< "oooops";exit(1);}
    }
            cout << "oooops";

}
```

Видно я что то не понимаю. За пределы массива вроде нигде не выхожу. Последний цикл успешно завершается, но вместо последнего вывода в консоли видно Segmentation fault. Голову сломал. Help please.

[image: Segfaut]
[image: Вариант с push_back и содержимое читаемого файла]

Comment: А зачем вам `num = num -1;`? Я так понял, в num вы храните что-то вроде количества записей, начинаете его с 0, при чтении каждой увеличиваете. Таким образом, прочитав 4 записи, при выходе из цикла num будет как раз равен количеству записей.

Comment: Вообще в целом подход с `resize + [] =` не безопасен. Может быть лучше просто читать записи и сразу их складывать через `push_back()` в вектор? Куча возможных проблем пропадет

Comment: Скрины приложил. У меня появляется на один элемент больше при чтении файла, по непонятной мне причине. поэтому num-1

Comment: И сам segfault выползает в конце функции InitFBD, сразу после цикла, т.к как cout <<  "ooops" уже не выводится. Это я так понимаю ><

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Неправильно передавал объект класса в функцию (Shm mymem).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте не использовать потенциально опасное обращение к несуществующему элементу вектора через `at()`, он же оператор `[]`:

```
void GetNames(vector<string> &names, vector<string> &types) {

if (!FlashHere()) return;

string buf;
ifstream in(NAMES_DIR);

while (!in.eof()) {
    getline(in, buf, '.');
    types.push_back(buf);

    getline(in, buf, ';');
    names.push_back(buf);

    cout<< "|" << names.back() << "|" << types.back() << "|" << endl;
}

in.close();
```

Самая частая ошибка при работе с вектором - думать, что вектор это просто динамический массив. Это С++, тут само ничего не происходит, и даже если расширение `data` у вектора спрятано под капотом STL, знать о нем и о его механике работы мы все равно обязаны

Comment: Возникает проблема с лишней ячейкой. Не пойму откуда это берется. Приложил скрины.

Comment: Так же пробовал заполнять/выводить именно методом .at(). Он же вроде как сообщает, о том что программа выходит за пределы массива. Только в моем случае результат был такой же.

Comment: В любом случае, даже если убрать exit(1) из конца цикла, результат seg fault.

Comment: Лишний элемент у вас возникает из-за чтения на конца файла, getline() читает что-то между последним `;` и EOF и возвращает это дело, а вы думаете, что это еще один элемент. В любом случае, добавьте побольше отладочного вывода на каждый чих, чтобы посмотреть, что просисходит

Comment: у меня такое впечатление что как то некоректно работает вывод. (iostream). потому что когда я вырезал совершенно другой кусок кода, появилась другая ошибка, segfault пропал.

Comment: я не понимаю что тут происходит. как будто программа не по порядку выполняется, а маленькими кусочками отовсюду

Comment: А что вам мешает просто на каждой строку поставить `cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;` и смотреть по порядку, выводя все интересующие вас переменные?

Comment: ошибка 100% в функции InitFBD. Потому что без нее все работает нормально и программа завершется. Стоит только вернуть этот блок, как ошибка возвращается

Comment: Ваш цикл for будет работать только при условии, что размеры обоих векторов names и types равны. Проверьте это в первую очередь выводом обоих размеров, а лучше - отдельной проверкой перед циклом.